# Name for Cartesian Product variant that does not return an empty set if one of the sets is empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I am looking for the name of this mathematical operation that behaves very similar to Cartesian Product.

Given:

- `A = {1,2}`
- `B = {3,4}`
- `C = {5}`
- `D = ∅`

The operation (which I'll write as `*`), behaves like this:

- `A * B = {1,2} * {3,4} = {(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)}` // Same as a Cartesian Product
- `A * C = {1,2} * {5} = {(1,5),(2,5)}` // Same as a Cartesian Product
- `A * D = {1,2} * ∅ = {1,2}` // Different from a Cartesian Product
- `D * A = ∅ * {1,2}  = {1,2}` // Different from a Cartesian Product

Furthermore:

- `A * B * C = {1,2} * {3,4} * {5} = {(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,3,5),(2,4,5)}` // Same as a Cartesian Product
- `A * C * D = {1,2} * {5} * ∅ = {(1,5),(2,5)}` // Different from a Cartesian Product
- `A * D * D = {1,2} * ∅ * ∅ = {1,2}` // Different from a Cartesian Product

Generally, this is the formal definition of that operator:

- `A * B = A × B` *if* `A ≠ ∅` and `B ≠ ∅`
- `A * B = A` *if* `B = ∅`
- `A * B = B` *if* `A = ∅`
- `A * B = ∅` *if* `A = ∅` and `B = ∅`

**What's the correct name for that operation?**

Comment: Is the operator limited to $A,B,C,D$ or is it generally defined for all sets?

Comment: This operation does not really exist in common mathematics usage. If you supply some context for your problem it might be possible to help you further.

Comment: @AsafKaragila generally defined for all sets

Comment: @IttayWeiss It's in [a programming context](http://www.optaplanner.org/), but I am using common math terminology to name my operations (which fits better than other terminologies such as SQL etc).

Comment: Suppose that $A,C\neq\varnothing$. What is $A*\varnothing*C$? Is it $(A*\varnothing)*C=A\times C$ or $A*(\varnothing*C)=A$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In that case, `A∗∅∗C = A*C`. Also `∅∗C = C`. I 'll update that in the question.

Comment: So in short, $A*B=A\times B$ if neither is empty, or $A\cup B$ if at least one of the sets is empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. Good point. Maybe I should call it "Cartesian product with union of empty sets" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am unaware of this sort of operations. But one can easily define it to be $$A*B=\begin{cases} A\times B & \text{if } A\times B\neq\varnothing\\ A\cup B & \text{if }A\times B=\varnothing\end{cases}$$

That is a legitimate mathematical definition, even if a bit peculiar generally.

Comment: As no name exists, I 'll need to give it an intuitive name myself. How about *Empty set ignoring Cartesian Product*?

Comment: That is a horrible name. Names should be concise.